# Single textinput component to handle password validation, login and email validation

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-native, authentication

***Question***

Thanks to the props could I make a single textInput custom component to handle differents validations ?

***Code***

Down below you will find the main Login screen, it's really simple and it consists in 2 text inputs.

```
import React, { PureComponent, } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import MkTextInput from '../../components/MkTextInput'


class LoginScreen extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
  }

  textChanged = fieldName => newValue => this.setState({ [fieldName]: newValue });

  render() {

    const { username } = this.state;

    return(
      <View>
        <MkTextInput placeholderName='Username' usernameValidation value={username} onChangeText={this.textChanged('username')}/>
        <MkTextInput placeholderName='Password' passwordValidation value={username} onChangeText={this.textChanged('password')} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default LoginScreen;
```

Down below here is the MkTextInputComponent

```
import React, { PureComponent, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Item, Input, Icon } from 'native-base';
import { userValidation, isTooShort } from '../utils/Validations/UserAndPassValidation';
import { passwordValidator } from '../utils/Validations/PasswordValidation';
import { styles } from './styles';

//ricorda di tradurre tutti i path in path assoluti -->leggi la documentazione.

class MkTextInput extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    data: '',
  }

  render() {
    const { placeholderName, 
            usernameValidation, 
            passwordValidation, 
            emailValidation, 
            onChangeText, 
            value,

          } = this.props;

    const checkedUsername = usernameValidation ? userValidation(value) : false;
    const checkedPassword = passwordValidation ? passwordValidator (value) : false;

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Item style={styles.container}>
          <Input placeholder={placeholderName} 
              onChangeText={onChangeText}  
              secureTextEntry={checkedUsername? true : false}
              style={checkedUsername ? styles.success : styles.failed}
              />
          <Icon name={checkedUsername ? 'checkmark-circle' : 'close-circle'}/>
        </Item>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default MkTextInput;
```

***The plan***

my first intention was to set a specified behaviour based on the props that the MkTextInput components will receive: If you have the props "passwordValidation" the component will deal the validation of the string with this line of code, and will ignore the remaining validation.

```
    const checkedPassword = passwordValidation ? passwordValidator (value) : false;
```

unluckly this way brings me to has several re-rendering of the same component, or to change the style of the password field just only writing in the username field.

There is a way to make things works ?

Comment: if you need more slices of my code i will be happy to post it, i didn't post it now just to avoid verbose and long topic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that after several tries i got an answer. Here is my solution:

```
Login component: 

import React, { PureComponent, } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import MkTextInput from '../../components/MkTextInput'


class LoginScreen extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
    email: '',
  }

  textChanged = fieldName => newValue => this.setState({ [fieldName]: newValue });

  render() {

    const { username, password, email } = this.state;

    return(
      <View>
        <MkTextInput placeholderName='Username' usernameValidation value={username} onChangeText={this.textChanged('username')} />
        <MkTextInput placeholderName='Password' passwordValidation value={password} onChangeText={this.textChanged('password')} />
        <MkTextInput placeholderName='E-mail' emailValidation value={email} onChangeText={this.textChanged('email')} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default LoginScreen;
```

And down below you will find the MkTextInput component

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { Item, Input, Icon } from 'native-base';
import { usernameValidator, passwordValidator, emailValidator } from '../utils/Validations';
import { styles } from './styles';
//ricorda di tradurre tutti i path relativi in path assoluti -->leggi la documentazione.

class MkTextInput extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    data: '',
  }

  render() {
    const { placeholderName, 
            usernameValidation, 
            passwordValidation, 
            emailValidation, 
            onChangeText, 
            value,
          } = this.props;

    const checkedUsername = usernameValidator(value) ? <Icon name='checkmark-circle'/> : !value || (value !== null && <Icon name='close-circle'/>);
    const checkedPassword = passwordValidator(value) ? <Icon name='checkmark-circle' /> : !value || (value !== null && <Icon name='close-circle'/>);
    const checkedEmail = emailValidator(value) ? <Icon name='checkmark-circle' /> : !value || (value !== null && <Icon name='close-circle' />); 

    return (
        <Item style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <Input placeholder={placeholderName || ''} 
              onChangeText={onChangeText}
              autoCapitalize='none'
              secureTextEntry={passwordValidation ? true : false}
              />
          {usernameValidation ? checkedUsername : null}
          {passwordValidation ? checkedPassword : null}
          {emailValidation ? checkedEmail : null}
        </Item>
    );
  }
}

export default MkTextInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

**unluckly this way brings me to has several re-rendering of the same component, or to change the style of the password field just only writing in the username field.**

The above statement is a bit confusing. Are you trying to say that when you enter/type in username field your password field changes styles?

Oh and btw your below code has a mistake. I guess the `value` props of password field should be `value={password}` instead of `value={username}`

```
return(
      <View>
        <MkTextInput placeholderName='Username' usernameValidation value={username} onChangeText={this.textChanged('username')}/>
        <MkTextInput placeholderName='Password' passwordValidation value={password} onChangeText={this.textChanged('password')} />
      </View>
    )
```

Maybe if you can give a little more description on what exactly you are stuck at or your code then maybe I would be able to help.